# How can I deploy next.js app on Firebase when the project are multiple sites?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, next.js, firebase-hosting

I have multiple sites on Firebase hosting for different environments (dev, stage, live),
and I have a Firebase function which runs a `next.js` app.

How can I deploy the app as per the environment while using multi-site hosting?

Comment: You can create multiple firebase projects for each env. That's usually preferable because you want to give devs access to dev but not all of them need access to prod. If you want to have everything in single project than you will need multiple functions.

Answer (score 2):

As [pagep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1768843/pagep) has mentioned, [it's recommended that you have separate projects for production and development environments](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/test-preview-deploy#:%7E:text=We%20recommend%20setting%20up%20a%20separate%20Firebase%20project%20for%20testing%20and%20developing%20your%20web%20app). For both security reasons and ease of management.

Mind you, you can setup preview channels, though their use is for previews, not for staging, and not for development (though you could use as a way to test things within your development environment). You can find more information about live/preview channels [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-hosting-resources).